# How do you think when you are asked to make an application in java?

Tags: java, javabeans, software-design

What process is best suited while making a software in java?
After a long while i came with this that you imagine how you want that application to behave. Then you classify the data into groups.You create classes which consists of the grouped data as fields and also include methods which allow you to access them and allow to communicate them.Then once you have objects that are necessary for your application you create interfaces that consists of methods(features) of your application.This is as far i have reached but the doubt that i have is the model that i described about objects sounds like java **beans** yet i never see them in any of the open source projects.I am curious as to why?Also i would like to know the drawbacks of using java beans...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

java beans are are plain java class with private attribute and public getter/setter methods... It wont have access to special access to special objects like SessionContext,EntityContext which EJB beans have, Which will be useful in J2EE application